# How to detect if the React app is actually being viewed on mobile menu actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, event-handling, dom-events

I have a React app, I've added eventlisteners to the window. So, this way I can detect if the user actually viewing the page or not. On computer browser, everything works as expected.

But I tried this on IphoneX (it's irrelevant but the browser was Safari), and I came across this: If the user **holds the bottom of the menu and swipe away all the open ones**, then **onBlur doesn't work**. It stays on the onFocus event. So actually window.eventlistener not working properly on mobile.

Also, when I open the browser again (but not clicking anything, just opening the browser and view the page) onFocus event also not working. It waits for me to touch or click somewhere on the page.

How to handle user focus/blur completely on mobile side?

Comment: Can you please add a snippet of your logic? Also, can you better explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think I already explained well, it's simple, handling focus and blur events on mobile browsers completely because window.addeventlistener(focus) and blur does not fully work, as I've explained above. I don't think I should put a snippet since if you aware of window.addeventlistener, I could only put 2 lines of code: window.addeventlistener("focus", function) and same for blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue using below event listeners.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleActivity);
document.addEventListener("blur", handleActivityFalse);
window.addEventListener("blur", handleActivityFalse);
window.addEventListener("focus", handleActivityTrue);
document.addEventListener("focus", handleActivityTrue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) for iOS / Safari supported events, they suggest `pageshow` and `pagehide` to listen for the kind of activity that I think you're talking about.

Comment: Well, it's actually worse than focus and blur. Now it doesn't even detect that I'm actually not viewing the window, blur was at least detecting when I leave the window (besides that swipe thing). I thought this might work to be honest, but right not it doesn't even detect when I'm clicking on the window etc.

Comment: I'd say to post a minimal reproducible example of the code then. Must be something in where / how you are adding event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame` to check if the user is watching the page.

```
function isWatching(){
        console.log("watching: " + Date.now());
    requestAnimationFrame(isWatching);
}
requestAnimationFrame(isWatching);
```

See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/t2r1sp56/ and you should also read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.navigator` to get all OS and browser info

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibilityChange` event and for the complete compatibility, you need to use webkit, ms, etc. prefix. I hope it helps :)

```js
let visibilityEventName = '';
let hiddenProperty = '';

if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') {
  hiddenProperty = 'hidden';
  visibilityEventName = 'visibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hiddenProperty = 'msHidden';
  visibilityEventName = 'msvisibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hiddenProperty = 'webkitHidden';
  visibilityEventName = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
}

// check whether this API is available or not and then proceed
if (visibilityEventName) {
  document.addEventListener(visibilityEventName, () => {
    if (document[hiddenProperty]) {
      // not visible
    } else {
      // visible
    }
  }, false);
}
```